# How to log exceptions in Controller Advice when exceptions extends to ResponseStatusException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am unable to capture exceptions in controller advice and log those exceptions. The exceptions are extended to ResponseStatusException. I tried this out but it didnt work.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionHandler.class);

@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(
        @NonNull Exception ex,
        @Nullable Object body,
        @NonNull HttpHeaders headers,
        HttpStatus status,
        @NonNull WebRequest request) {
    if (status.is5xxServerError()) {
        LOGGER.error("An exception occurred, which will cause a {} response", status, ex);
    } else if (status.is4xxClientError()) {
        LOGGER.warn("An exception occured, which will cause a {} response", status, ex);
    } else {
        LOGGER.debug("An exception occured, which will cause a {} response", status, ex);
    }
    return super.handleExceptionInternal(ex, body, headers, status, request);
}
}
```

How could I achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not extending from ResponseEntityExceptionHandler as a first test.

Create an exception handler by doing something like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResponseStatusException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> testHandler(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("whatever", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

I suspect that you are not telling spring to handle this specific exception via:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResponseStatusException.class)
```